# C# .NET multiline TextBox with same-width characters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

How can I make it so if you typed in a multiline `TextBox`:

```
abcde

ABCDE
```

So that the big `E` is **directly** below the little `e`. I want them to line up vertically if they are in the same row.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Can you just set the font on the textbox to a [monospaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) one?

In code, keeping the same size as the default font:

```
textBox.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, textBox.Font.Size);
```

Or just change the `Font` property in the designer.

Comment: Learned a new word, what are some monospaced fonts?

Comment: Is it safe to use a font like consolas because I think I installed it myself or do all the font is VS come with the .net framework?

Comment: @Mark: I seem to remember that Consolas comes with Office... I can't remember what happens if you specify a font which isn't present on the deployed system. Who are your users?

Comment: Making an app for guitar chords and tabs, there generic one seems fine but is there a way to just package the font with the app

Comment: @Mark: I suspect that would be quite a lot of work - and you'd need to investigate the licensing etc. I'd stick to Courier New if I were you :)

Comment: That's what I'll do.  Looks good enough for me.  I have a visual editor and text editor so its not extremely important for it.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using a fixed width font.  Courier family fonts are often fixed width.

You can set the font in the property editor for the textbox control.  For example, you can set the Font property to **Courier New, 8.25pt**.

Answer (score 5):

Some fonts use different character widths for different characters. In such fonts an "m" will have a greater width than an "i". They are called **proportional** fonts. These fonts have a nicer-looking and are easier to read.

Fonts where all the characters have the same width are called **monospaced** fonts. They are often used for source code as they allow aligning features like line comments to right of the code.

Use a monospaced font!

Here is the code I use to get a list of all monospaced fonts installed:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PE.Rendering {

    static class FontHelper {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        class LOGFONT {
            public int lfHeight;
            public int lfWidth;
            public int lfEscapement;
            public int lfOrientation;
            public int lfWeight;
            public byte lfItalic;
            public byte lfUnderline;
            public byte lfStrikeOut;
            public byte lfCharSet;
            public byte lfOutPrecision;
            public byte lfClipPrecision;
            public byte lfQuality;
            public byte lfPitchAndFamily;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string lfFaceName;
        }

        static bool IsMonospaced(Graphics g, Font f)
        {
            float w1, w2;

                w1 = g.MeasureString("i", f).Width;
                w2 = g.MeasureString("W", f).Width;
                return w1 == w2;
        }

        static bool IsSymbolFont(Font font)
        {
            const byte SYMBOL_FONT = 2;

            LOGFONT logicalFont = new LOGFONT();
            font.ToLogFont(logicalFont);
            return logicalFont.lfCharSet == SYMBOL_FONT;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tells us, if a font is suitable for displaying document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Some symbol fonts do not identify themselves as such.</remarks>
        /// <param name="fontName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static bool IsSuitableFont(string fontName)
        {
            return !fontName.StartsWith("ESRI") && !fontName.StartsWith("Oc_");
        }

        public static List<string> GetMonospacedFontNames()
        {
            List<string> fontList = new List<string>();
            InstalledFontCollection ifc;

            ifc = new InstalledFontCollection();
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1)) {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                    foreach (FontFamily ff in ifc.Families) {
                        if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular) && ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold) 
                            && ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic) && IsSuitableFont( ff.Name)) {
                            using (Font f = new Font(ff, 10)) {
                                if (IsMonospaced(g,f) && !IsSymbolFont(f)) {
                                    fontList.Add(ff.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return fontList;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a monospaced or fixed width fonts.

Comment: Can you please Suggest some Fixed width fonts name ?? which like default font family.