# Line spacing in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to set the space between two lines in a TextBox Multiline?
I've tried this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbdesc" Text='<%# Eval("Descritivo") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="450px" LineSpacing="-9" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# .NET multiline TextBox with same-width characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285166/c-sharp-net-multiline-textbox-with-same-width-characters)

Comment: @MethodMan your proposed duplicate is for WinForms. This is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

Then using `TextMode="MultiLine"` it will render a `<textarea>` element in the client browser.  The vertical line spacing in the textarea can be changed with plain CSS using the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property.

For example, this would double-space the contents:

```
#txbdesc {
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a `line-height` CSS property on the `textarea`:

```css
.large {
    line-height: 20px;
}
.small {
    line-height: 10px;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="large">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ullamcorper orci ligula, vel mattis quam rutrum nec. In sollicitudin mi et laoreet vestibulum. Sed ante dolor, suscipit tincidunt tempor vel, accumsan at nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam posuere enim dictum turpis ultrices feugiat. Phasellus convallis vestibulum lacus in tristique.
</textarea>
<textarea class="small">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ullamcorper orci ligula, vel mattis quam rutrum nec. In sollicitudin mi et laoreet vestibulum. Sed ante dolor, suscipit tincidunt tempor vel, accumsan at nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam posuere enim dictum turpis ultrices feugiat. Phasellus convallis vestibulum lacus in tristique.
</textarea>
```