# How do I align text like columns in a treeview?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView where I want to arrange my data nicely.

I format my string like this:

```
string name = ItemName;
string current = ("Current: " + info.Current.ToString() + " " + identifier);
string maximum = ("Maximum: " + info.Max.ToString() + " " + identifier);
string minimum = ("Minimum: " + info.Min.ToString() + " " + identifier);

string output = string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-30}{2,-30}{3,-30}{4,-30}", name, current, maximum, minimum, average);
dataNode.Text = output;
```

When I write `output` to the console it prints it the way I want it, like this (values are off, but that's irrelevant):

```
Load                Current: 9,23 %               Maximum: 33,33 %              Minimum: 6,06 %               Average: 0 %
Temperature         Current: 40 °C                Maximum: 49 °C                Minimum: 38 °C                Average: 0 °C
Clock               Current: 1200 Mhz             Maximum: 2800,09 Mhz          Minimum: 1200 Mhz             Average: 0 Mhz
etc..
```

But when I print the exact same strings to my `TreeView` it shows it like this:
[image]

I followed the example on [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/) page but that didn't work for me.

I guess it has something to do with the different nodes I use in my `TreeView` but I don't know how to properly align my data.

Comment: seems like you need to set monospaced font for TreeView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285166/c-sharp-net-multiline-textbox-with-same-width-characters

Comment: @ASh This seems to be the perfect solution for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you need to set monospaced font for TreeView.

here is a similar question with example of monospaced font (`FontFamily.GenericMonospace`):

[C# .NET multiline TextBox with same-width characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285166/c-sharp-net-multiline-textbox-with-same-width-characters)

Comment: +1, this has fixed weird text alignment errors for me when nothing else works. Consolas is a popular monospace font. See here for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect situation for `.PadRight()` or `.PadLeft()`.

```
string output = 
        string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", 
                       name.PadRight(20), 
                       current.PadRight(30), 
                       maximum.PadRight(30), 
                       minimum.PadRight(30), 
                       average.PadRight(30));
```

This code will ensure that the space taken up by each parameter is the same every time.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't show in nicely arranged columns. Also whenever a percentage has only 1 decimal instead of 2, the rest of the line is moved to the left by one character. It's like the padLeft/padRight methods don't fill the extra characters needed.

Comment: No matter what you do, you will always face misalignment due the varying widths of individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other controls how alow to create columns like :

There are a number of sample controls to be found around the web:

[TreeViewAdv for .Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/)

[TreeView with Columns](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeWithColumns.aspx)

[ContainerListView and TreeListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/extendedlistviews.aspx)

Comment: ["Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try just to change font of treeView to use a

```
non-proportional font like "Courier" , "Consolas"
```