# String is displayed incorrectly in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to extend a string to a fixed length with spaces.
Now the problem is that in a textbox the text is displayed wrong.
If I output the same text in the console, it is correct.
What am I doing wrong?

```
machineData += String.Format("{0,-50} : {1,-50}\r\n", 
   AddSpacesAndSpecialCharactersToName(item), 
   GetSpecificDataOfSelectedMachine(item));

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-50} : {1,-50}\r\n", 
  AddSpacesAndSpecialCharactersToName(item), 
  GetSpecificDataOfSelectedMachine(item)));
```

It should look like this:

```
Text         : Value
LongerText   : Value
Sm           : Value
```

But in Textbox it look like:

```
Text     : Value
LongerText     : Value
Sm  : Value
```

Is it because of the text box?
I already tried to write the text into a label, there is the same problem.

Comment: So your question why spaces don't align text in `TextBox`? You have to use [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) for this to work. Change `TextBox` font to font like one used by `Console` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285209/1997232)). A better solution would be to solve that in layout: you can have header controls on the left and then verticaly aligned controls on the right to show the value.

Comment: Another option is to use a RichTextBox, define [SelectionTabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectiontabs) that express fixed positions (array of `int`) and set `RichTextBox.WordWrap = false; RichTextBox.AcceptsTab = true;`. This allows to space non-monospaced Fonts using a Tab (`\t`) that is independent from the width of the Text chars. Of course you need to measure the max length of your strings (in pixels, using `TextRenderer.MeasureText`) and set the tabs to values that are > of the max string length in each column.