# How do you control the size of a blank character in a TextBox or a MessageBox?

Tags: string, vb.net, textbox, ml.net

Picture (1) is the content of my string (This is an output of an ML.NET routine. I don't have control of it). Picture (2) is how the string looks like in a TextBox or a MessageBox.
The blank character size in a TextBox is slightly smaller than in a string. How can we fix that?

(1)

[image: The content of a string variable]

(2)

[image: string printed in a TextBox]

Comment: What kind of TextBox are you referring to? What GUI Platform? In any case, use a monospaced Font (e.g., Courier New, Consolas etc.)

Comment: Did you notice the font difference? One has font where each character (space included) has the same size, the other instead has characters of different size and thus no way to have a correct table aspect with just using spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure text alignment in vb.net textbox/Messagebox string, use-

1. MonoSpace font

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.genericmonospace?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

[C# .NET multiline TextBox with same-width characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285166/c-sharp-net-multiline-textbox-with-same-width-characters)

2. Add padding to each text piece to position it in desired location.